# Why does classic module resolution fail to find only one of my installed modules?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a node project with a few modules installed.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.11.1",
    "@types/express-fileupload": "^0.1.1",
    "@types/mongodb": "^3.0.12",
    "@types/npm": "^2.0.29",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-fileupload": "^0.4.0",
    "log4js": "^2.5.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.5"
  }
```

When I invoke the typescript compiler with tsc -p . I receive the following error:

> app.ts(5,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'log4js'.

I can get it to compile successfully by adding the following to my compiler options in tsconfig.json:

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

But why, under the default module resolution, is log4js the only module not found?  Since all the modules are in the same folder, I would the compiler to be able to locate either all, or none of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`log4js` has types specified in its `package.json`, but `classic` doesn't read `package.json` entries from non-`@types` folders.

As the naming implies, this is the "classic" behavior rather than behavior someone might actually want and is provided mostly for back-compat reasons.